# package org.kxml2.kdom does not exist

Tags: xml, java-me, kxml

I added a mini xpath processor into my  JavaME codes.
I get this error: package org.kxml2.kdom does not exist

How do I fix this?

Hope someone could help me on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153788/how-do-i-get-kxml-to-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to add the KXML jar file to your project resources.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that I needed to get kxml 1 not 2. Also, if you're using ktoolbar, put the jar or zip file (according which version you're using) in the lib file in your app